# Invalid certificate for "localhost" on Cloudflared

Tags: apache, https, xampp, cloudflare

I am running a web server (Wordpress) locally using XAMPP (using Apache) and forwarding it to my Cloudflare-hosted domain using a Cloudflared tunnel. I am having an issue with the certificate when connecting over my domain.

I have a certificate I received from Cloudflare which is valid for my domain installed in XAMPP's location for its certificate, and I know that it is being sent with the HTTPS result. Also, my "SSL/TLS encryption mode" on Cloudflare is "Full (Strict)".

When connecting from the browser, I get a 502 Bad Gateway error, and Cloudflared prints this error: `error="Unable to reach the origin service. The service may be down or it may not be responding to traffic from cloudflared: x509: certificate is valid for *.example.com, example.com, not localhost` where `example.com` is my domain.

If I go to

- `http://example.com` or `https://example.com`, I get the above error.
- `http://localhost`, the website loads but does not load any of the resources, since Wordpress loads the resources by querying the domain, `https://example.com/path/to/resource`.
- `https://localhost`, the same as above happens, but Chrome also give me a warning that the certificate is not valid.

Here are the ingress rules in Cloudflared's `config.yml`.

```
ingress:
  - hostname: ssh.example.com       # I haven't gotten this one to work yet.
    service: ssh://localhost:22
  - hostname: example.com           # This is the one having a problem.
    service: https://localhost
  - service: https://localhost
```

What I believe is happening is that Cloudflared receives the certificate which is valid for my domain (*.example.com, example.com) and then tries to execute the ingress rule by going to `https://localhost`, but the certificate is not valid for `localhost`. I don't think I should just get a certificate which is valid for `localhost` AND `example.com`. Do I need one certificate (valid for `localhost`) to be returned whenever `http(s)://localhost` is called and another (valid for `example.com`) that Cloudflared checks when it tries to execute an ingress rule involving example.com? If so, how do I do this?

Comment: `localhost` to ingress is not the same it is to you.  You can't use that name to access any computer through a remote network

Comment: Cloudflared is running on my computer, so when it sees `localhost`, it should go to my computer.

Answer (score 1):

I solved it by using the `noTLSVerify` option in Cloudflared's `config.yml`. When a client connects to my domain, it goes like this:

Client > Cloudflare > Cloudflared instance running on my machine > Origin (which also happens to be my machine: `https://localhost`)

The certificate sent back by the Origin was not valid for the address Cloudflared was accessing it from, `localhost`, but by adding these lines to `config.yml`,

```
originRequest: 
  noTLSVerify: true
```

I think Cloudflared does not check the certificate received from the origin, although it still returns the certificate to Cloudflare, which checks it against my domain.

Comment: Note that `no-tls-verify: true` on the top level of the config is **not** sufficient. You must have the `originRequest` and `noTLSVerify` in this answer too. The use of camel case for these options does not match the rest of my config, but that doesn't seem to matter. Great answer, thanks!